# Import stylesheed based on screen width

Tags: css

This won t work. how can i accomplish something similar?

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
   @import url("style480.css");
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just put css style in separate files, and inside them use media queries?

Comment: @import url(blue.css) (min-width:800px); try this

Comment: Please check this link http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="style480.css" />
```